# Determine the percentile of the score distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

The score of a student on a certain exam is represented by a number between 0 and 1. Suppose that the student passes the exam if this number is at least 0.55. Suppose we model this experiment by a continuous random variable S, the score, whose probability density function is given by:

$$\ f(x) = \begin{cases} 4x & 0 \le x \le .5\\ 4-4x & .5 \le x \le 1\\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}$$

1)What is the probability that the student fails the exam?

2)What is the score that he will obtain with a 50% chance, in other words, what is the 50th percentile of the score distribution?

For question #1 I got:

$$f(.55) = P(X\le.55) = \int_{-\infty}^{.55} f(x) \,dx $$
Which gave me
$$\int_{0}^{.5} 4x \,dx +\int_{.5}^{.55} (4-4x) \,dx$$
Which when worked out I got
$$P(X\lt .55) = 0.595 $$

My question is regarding #2 is it as simple as 

$\int_{0}^{.5} 4x \,dx$ = 0.5 

The score that will be obtained with a 50% chance is m = 0.5?

Or do I need to use: 

$\mu =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \,dx$ 

and

$ \sigma^2 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2f(x) \,dx - \mu^2$ 

Any Advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer of $m=.5$ is correct, but in general it comes from solving the following equation for $m$:

$$ P(X \leq m) = \int_0^m f(x) \, dx = .5 $$

The left hand side is also known as the **cumulative distribution function** $F$ (evaluated at $m$). You can write it in two cases:

Case 1. If $m<.5$, then
$$
\int_0^m f(x) \, dx = \int_0^m 4x \, dx = 2m^2
$$
Case 2. If $m \geq .5$ then
$$
\int_0^m f(x) \, dx = \int_0^.5 4x \, dx + \int_.5^m (4-4x) \, dx= 1 -   2(1-m)^2 
$$
Exercise to the reader: Prove the above integrals.

Putting it togethers yields the cdf:
$$
F(m) = \begin{cases}
2m^2 & 0 \leq m < .5 \\
1 -   2(1-m)^2  & .5 \leq m \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

One can easily see that $F(m) = .5$ is satisfied whenever $m=.5$.